# Building a Swift Package with Salesforce Mobile SDK dependency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I am trying to build a Swift Package which depends on Salesforce Mobile SDK (`MobileSync` library). I didn't find any Swift Package for Salesforce mobile SDK yet, so I was trying to use the `MobileSync` pod.

**What I tried?**

These are the steps I followed

- I created a new framework project (let's called it `MobileSyncSPM`)
- Initialized pod file and added `MobileSync` dependency
- I thought of exposing all the public interfaces for the `MobileSync` package by importing it from framework header file. So, in the framework Header file of the framework (`MobileSyncSPM.h` file), added an import for `MobileSync.h` header file

```
#import <MobileSync/MobileSync.h>
```

- Changed the build settings for the target `Build Libraries for Distribution` to `YES`.
- Archived the workspace project

```
xcodebuild archive \
-workspace MobileSyncSPM.xcworkspace \
-scheme MobileSyncSPM \
-configuration Debug \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
-archivePath './build/MobileSyncSPM.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

```
xcodebuild archive \
-workspace MobileSyncSPM.xcworkspace \
-scheme MobileSyncSPM \
-configuration Debug \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
-archivePath './build/MobileSyncSPM.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

- Generated `XCFramework` binary for the archives

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework './build/MobileSyncSPM.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MobileSyncSPM.framework' \
-framework './build/MobileSyncSPM.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MobileSyncSPM.framework' \
-output './build/MobileSyncSPM.xcframework'
```

- I added the `XCFramework` binary under the `Sources` on Swift Package.
- In `Package.swift` file, I tried to add the `XCFramework` binary as a `binaryTarget` as follows -

```
targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MyUtils",
            dependencies: [
                .byName(name: "MobileSyncSPM")
            ]
        ),
        .binaryTarget(name: "MobileSyncSPM", path: "Sources/MyUtils/MobileSyncSPM.xcframework"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyUtilsTests",
            dependencies: ["MyUtils"]
        ),
    ]
```

- The Swift Package builds successfully with the binary target.

The problem occurs when I try to import the `XCFramework` library (`MobileSyncSPM`) from inside the Swift Package.

So inside a swift file under the swift package, if I add the following import

```
import MobileSyncSPM
```

I get the error that says

```
Could not build Objective-C module MobileSyncSPM
```

Looking forward to your suggestions on fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same problem. However, I found an issue on Github that has been open for a frighteningly long time already: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/3277

Until Salesforce decides to provide the MobileSync via Swift Package Manager, this can be included via CocoaPods, among others.

```
source 'https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Specs.git'

target 'App' do
    pod 'MobileSync'
end
```

Use it in your project with `import MobileSync`